# API Google Calendar PHP

Tags: php, api, google-calendar

estoy intentando añadir invitados al crear un evento de Google Calendar.

Consigo crear correctamente el evento pero no consigo añadir los invitados:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Atlantic/Canary');
include_once '/autoload.php';

putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=xxxxxxxxxxx.json');

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']);

$id_calendar='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@group.calendar.google.com';

$datetime_start = new DateTime($_POST['date_start']);
$datetime_end = new DateTime($_POST['date_start']);

$time_end = $datetime_end->add(new DateInterval('PT1H'));

$time_start =$datetime_start->format(\DateTime::RFC3339);
$time_end=$time_end->format(\DateTime::RFC3339);

$calendarService = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event();
$event->setSummary('Revisión');
$event->setDescription('Revisión Depósito');
$event->setLocation('Calle España');

$attendee = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventAttendee();
$attendee->setEmail("supp@gmail.com");
$attendees = array($attendee);
$event->setAttendees([$attendees]);

$start = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
$start->setDateTime($time_start);
$event->setStart($start);

$end = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
$end->setDateTime($time_end);
$event->setEnd($end);

$createdEvent = $calendarService->events->insert($id_calendar, $event);
```

Se crea perfectamente el evento pero no se añaden los invitados, y como no devuelve ningún error no se que puede estar pasando.

Answer (score 0):

La razón por la que el invitado no se está agregando se debe a que estás pasando un arreglo de arreglos como parámetro del método `setAttendess`. Para que esto funcione, tienes que pasar un arreglo de invitados. De modo que tu código tiene que ser así:

```
$attendee = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventAttendee();
$attendee->setEmail("supp@gmail.com");
$attendees = array($attendee);
$event->setAttendees($attendees);
```

O si solamente es un invitado siempre, puede ser así también:

```
$attendee = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventAttendee();
$attendee->setEmail("supp@gmail.com");
$event->setAttendees([$attendee]);
```

Cualquiera de los das formas, la que uses debe satisfacer la solicitud.

Comment: No funciona con ninguna de las formas que me has indicado, me devuelve: "Calendar usage limits exceeded."

Comment: @Pablo Ah, ese error ya es otra cuestión. Significa que los límites del uso del calendario ya se pasaron o que tu autenticación no es la correcta. De todas formas, la respuesta que te di es para el error en específico que estabas teniendo. Este es otro error, para ayudarte con eso debés editar tu pregunta y sus detalles.

Comment: Pues sigo sin encontrar solución...

Comment: ¿Qué? La solución que te di no puede estár más clara. ¿Seguro que entiendes la solución que he planteado?